# Pathfinder Tengu Race in PCGen

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pcgen

My issue is as follows: when selecting Tengu as my player character race in PCGen, it's not fully updating the summary page and is ommitting certain characteristics for the race.

This is causing PCGen to go wonky and not fully update all other aspects of the character.

An example would be that the Movement speed of the race is not being pulled through and this happens to be impacting skills oddly.

How does one fix this? I'm using PCGen 6.7 alpha

Comment: Without knowing anything about the software and not much about Pathfinder: using an alpha version of software is always "risky". There might be a bug there. Have you reported the bug to the developers and tried using a stable version? What did the developers tell you about this behaviour?

Comment: Do note that thought he is using an *alpha* release, [PCGen](http://pcgen.org/download/) has several stable releases, it's not an unfinished software.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a **bug on the software**.

You can go to their [Contact Us](http://pcgen.org/contact-us/) page and report the problem to their webmaster. Or [Report an Issue](https://github.com/PCGen/pcgen/issues) on their GitHub project site. Or even [look at the code](https://github.com/PCGen/pcgen) yourself if you are familiar with the language (mostly Java).

They also have other direct means of contact:

- [Live chat](https://www.hipchat.com/gzYdCc3Vn);
- [Community Forum](http://groups.pcgen.org/), at the [Question & Issues](http://groups.pcgen.org/viewforum.php?f=9) subforum;
- [E-mail](http:////help@pcgen.org).

I can tell you that the *Sneaky* racial ability has [not been working properly](http://groups.pcgen.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=136&p=600&hilit=tengu#p600) since version 6.02, but is now fixed on **6.06 stable**. I see no problem with movement speed on 6.06 either, so the problem could be on your *non-stable* version (it is *alpha* for a reason).